# Pandas time series indexing -- re

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe indexed by time:

```
>>> dframe.head()
                     aw_FATFREEMASS raw aw_FATFREEMASS sym
TIMESTAMP
2011-12-08 23:13:23               139.3                  H
2011-12-08 23:12:18               139.2                  H
2011-12-08 22:31:53               139.2                  H
2011-12-09 07:08:50               138.2                  H
2011-12-10 21:36:20               137.6                  H

[5 rows x 2 columns]

>>> type(dframe.index)
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
```

I'm trying to do a simple time series query similar to this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM dframe WHERE tstart <= TIMESTAMP <= tend
```

where tstart and tend are appropriately represented timestamps.  With pandas I'm getting behavior I just don't understand.

This does what I expect:

```
>>> dframe['2011-11-01' : '2011-11-20']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [aw_FATFREEMASS raw, aw_FATFREEMASS sym]
Index: []
[0 rows x 2 columns]
```

This does the same thing:

```
dframe['2011-11-01 00:00:00' : '2011-11-20 00:00:00']
```

However:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dframe[parse('2011-11-01 00:00:00') : '2011-11-20 00:00:00']
*** TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
>>> dframe[parse('2011-11-01') : '2011-11-20 00:00:00']
*** TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
>>> dframe[parse('2011-11-01') : parse('2011-11-01')]
*** KeyError: Timestamp('2011-11-01 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

When I provide a time represented as a pandas Timestamp I get slice behavior I don't understand.  Can someone explain this behavior and/or tell me how I can achieve the SQL query above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing)

This is called partial string indexing. In a nutshell, providing a string will get you results that 'match', e.g. they are included in the specified interval, while if you specify a Timestamp/datetime then its exact; it HAS to be in the index.

Can you show how you constructed the DatetimeIndex?

what version pandas?

```
In [4]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,2),index=date_range('20130101',periods=20,freq='H'))

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
                            0         1
2013-01-01 00:00:00 -0.339751  1.223660
2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.525203 -0.987815
2013-01-01 02:00:00  1.724239  0.213446
2013-01-01 03:00:00 -0.074797 -1.658876
2013-01-01 04:00:00  0.483425 -2.112314
2013-01-01 05:00:00  0.094140  0.327681
2013-01-01 06:00:00 -1.265337 -0.858521
2013-01-01 07:00:00 -1.470041  0.168871
2013-01-01 08:00:00 -0.609185  0.829035
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.047774  0.221399
2013-01-01 10:00:00  0.814162 -1.415824
2013-01-01 11:00:00  1.070209  0.720150
2013-01-01 12:00:00  0.887571 -0.611207
2013-01-01 13:00:00  1.669451 -0.022434
2013-01-01 14:00:00 -1.796565 -1.186899
2013-01-01 15:00:00  0.417758  0.082021
2013-01-01 16:00:00 -1.064019 -0.377208
2013-01-01 17:00:00  0.939902  0.430784
2013-01-01 18:00:00 -0.645667  1.611992
2013-01-01 19:00:00 -0.172148 -1.725041

[20 rows x 2 columns]

In [6]: df['20130101 7:00:01':'20130101 10:00:00']
Out[6]: 
                            0         1
2013-01-01 08:00:00 -0.609185  0.829035
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.047774  0.221399
2013-01-01 10:00:00  0.814162 -1.415824

[3 rows x 2 columns]

In [7]: df.index
Out[7]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-01-01 19:00:00]
Length: 20, Freq: H, Timezone: None
```

If you already have Timestamps/datetimes, then just construct a boolean expression

```
df[(df.index > Timestamp('20130101 10:00:00')) & (df.index < Timestamp('201301010 17:00:00')])
```

Comment: It's pandas 0.13.1 (most recent). The dataframe is created by read_csv, which constructs the DatetimeIndex.   The query timestamps come from other frames' indices so they're pandas.tslib.Timestamp objects.  There must be a more natural way of doing retrieval than converting Timestamps back to strings.  Thanks.

Comment: sure...updated the answer. just do normal boolean indexing, using ``df.index``